# React js render functional html with json response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

i have created dropdown component like

```
  const CONTACTS_LIST = () => (

    <select>
    {
    list_data &&
    list_data .map((h, i) => 
    (
    <option key={i} value={h.list_id}>{h.name}</option>))
    }
    </select>

  );
```

can it be possible to render html with json response like this ?. i can set reponse in constants using setstate . but just wanted to know that is it also possible ?

```
    const CONTACTS_LIST = () => (

      fetch(URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
      (
        render '
        (   <select>
        {
        json &&
        json.map((h, i) => 
        (
        <option key={i} value={h.list_id}>{h.name}</option>))
        }
        </select>
        )

        )
    );
```

please suggest

Comment: Please format your code and be clear about what you are asking; it will help us understand your question and what you've tried. Your second snippet doesn't have valid syntax, and your third snippet is incomplete.

Comment: i am asking that can component html can be render with json reponse ?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous requests are recommended to be made within the componentDidMount method, with the data you get from the api update the status of the component, when updating the status the component will be re-rendered and it will be verified if it has elements, if it has then the options of the .
I hope it helps you.

```
class MyComponent{
  constructor () {
    super();

    this.state = {
      list_data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const URL = "";
    fetch(URL).then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          list_data: json
        });
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <select>
        {
          list_data.length === 0
            ? <option value="">Waiting moment</option>
            : list_data.map(({ h, i }) => (
              <option key={i} value={h.list_id}>{h.name}</option>
            ))
        }
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

if you are using react 16 you can use the Hooks, useState and useEffect, try it this way

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function myComponent () {
  const [list_data, set_list_data] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const URL = "";
    fetch(URL).then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        set_list_data(json);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <select>
      {
          list_data.length === 0
            ? <option value="">Waiting moment</option>
            : list_data.map(({ h, i }) => (
              <option key={i} value={h.list_id}>{h.name}</option>
            ))
        }
    </select>
  );
}
```

[Hook feature reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: you need the component with cycle so you can get asynchronous data, the life cycle is obtained by inheriting the Component class.
Depending on the React version you can use the Hooks that are used to create component functions with asynchronous data. what version of react are you using @NeerajVerma .

Comment: @JorgeMartinezJimenez You have a syntax error: `['']` should be `[]`. You are passing no dependencies to the effect. You should also check if the component is still [mounted[(https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted) before setting state.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the json response as a prop to the component to be rendered.

```
fetch(URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
          <Component data={response} />
      )
```

Having html code in the `then` block kind of defeats React's purpose.